# Adding values in a sample

Tags: r, sample, dice

If I have a sample of numbers, say a set of dice rolls given by:

```
Rolls <- sample(1:6, 4, replace = TRUE)
```

What I would like to do is take any two values in the sample set and be able to add them, however, after adding them I'd like to put the new value into the sample AND remove the values that were used in the addition.

For example, say my sample is 2 4 3 6 and I choose to add 4 and 6, I would then want my sample to look like this: 2 3 10 (the order they are arranged in isn't important for me)

(Side note: It would also be great if the code would then ask the user if they'd like to add the 2 leftover values or not, in the case I've given, after adding 10 to the sample and removing 4 and 6, it would then ask "would you like to add your other two values?" and if the user says yes it would add 2 and 3, put 5 in the sample then remove 2 and 3, same as for 4 and 6.)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I would write a function to handle this. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Yes, that's where I want to implement this code, as part of a function, I've got the dice rolls set up and it can take the values and add them, what I'm not sure how to do is then put the new value in the sample I have.

Comment: What does it happen if roles is something like 1,4,4,4 and you want to remove 1 and 4? Or 4 and 4? remove randomly one or two of the 4?

Comment: Yeah I guess it can be random since it won't change the outcome, the order of my sample is not important, all that matters is that the values that get added together are then removed. So if we get 1,4,4,4 and we want to add 1 and 4, we take 1 and ANY of the 4's, we would then put 5 in the sample and remove the 1 and 4, the new sample would be 4,4,5 (or 5,4,4 or 4,5,4 it doesn't matter to me)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution you could use.

```
# Create our Array of four
Rolls<-sample(1:6, 4, replace = TRUE)
cat("Values from our sample are: ", Rolls)

# Auxiliary variable to check if the input is correct
selectedVariables <- FALSE
values <- vector()

# Get the selected variables by the user
while(!selectedVariables){
  number <- readline(prompt='Write two values from the sample (separate them using a comma): ')
  # Transform input to int array
  values <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(number,",")))
  
  # Check if both values are in the array considering repetitions 
  # (if the user select twice the same number and there is only one in the sample reject the input given)
  if(values[1] %in% Rolls & values[2] %in% Rolls[-match(values[1],Rolls) & length(values)==2]){
    selectedVariables = TRUE
  }
  else{
    cat("Please select two valid values from the sample. Example: ", sample(Rolls,2))
  }
}

# Depending on whether or not they are equal, we will use "which" or "match"
if (values[1] == values[2]){
  # If they are equal we'll use which to get both positions of this values
  RollsAux<- append(Rolls[! 1:length(Rolls) %in% which(Rolls %in% values)], sum(values))
}else{
  # If they are different we'll get only the first appearance in our array of four
  RollsAux<- append(Rolls[! 1:length(Rolls) %in% match(values,Rolls)], sum(values))
}

ans <- readline(prompt="Would you like to add up the other numbers? [y/n] ")

if (ans == "y" || ans == "Y"){
  # If the user wants to sum the other two values this adds up the first two values in a new array with the last result
  Result<- append(RollsAux[length(RollsAux)], sum(RollsAux[1:length(RollsAux)-1]))
}else{
  # If not, the resulting array will be the same as our auxiliary array 
  Result <- RollsAux
}
```

Like I've mentioned in the comments you could also force the user to insert the positions of the values that he wants to select like this:

```
while(!selectedVariables){
  number <- readline(prompt='Write the positions of the two values from the sample (separate them using a comma): ')
  # Transform input to int array
  values <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(number,",")))
  # Check if the user has given the same position twice
  if (any(duplicated(values))){
    print("Positions need to be different.")
  }
  else{
    # Checks if all the positions given are in the length of the array
    if(all(values <= length(Rolls))&length(values)==2){
      values <- Rolls[values]
      selectedVariables = TRUE
    }
    else{
      print("Positions selected exceed length of array sample.")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm trying to achieve, the only thing I need to adjust is that instead of "aux" being a random selection of 2 numbers in the Rolls Array, I need it to take two values that the user decides, after that the rest of the code is what I think I'm looking for. So i need to change what "aux" is defined as from being "sample(Rolls,2)" to something that lets the user select two values from the Rolls sample.

Comment: Any idea how I'd change this? I've tried using "readline(prompt...)" but I'm not sure how to ensure the values they choose are within the sample set (so they can't just pick any value they please) and to then use the value they choose for the rest of the code.

Comment: @Maximus No problem. In that case, you could force the user to insert the positions of the numbers in the sample that he wants to select or use the method given in my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

As in your previous question we can utilize `scan()` to handle user input.

**Code**

```
sum.dice <- function(Roll, p1, p2){
  
  #  extract values
  tmp1 <- Roll[c(p1, p2)]

  # ad and remove
  tmp2 <- c(Roll[-c(p1, p2)], sum(tmp1))
  
  # User input whether to add remaining wo numbers
  cat("Your sample currently looks as follows: \n\n",
      tmp2
      ,"\n\n Would you like to sum up the remaining two entries of your sample?")
  
  # scan
  tmp3 <- scan(what = "")
  
  # add remaining values if so desired
  if(tolower(tmp3) == "yes"){
    c(sum(Roll[-c(p1, p2)]), sum(tmp1))
  } else{
    tmp2
  }
}

sum.dice(Rolls, 3, 4)

# Your sample currently looks as follows: 
# 
#  5 3 6 
# 
#  Would you like to sum up the remaining two entries of your sample?
# 1: no
# 2: ""
# Read 1 item
# [1] 5 3 6

# or

# Your sample currently looks as follows: 
# 
#  5 3 6 
# 
#  Would you like to sum up the remaining two entries of your sample?
# 1: yes
# 2: ""
# Read 1 item
# [1] 8 6
```

Comment: I think it could break up if `Rolls <- c(2,6,2,6); sum.dice(Rolls, 2, 6)`, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @s__ yes, thanks for pointing that out ! It could if  `p1` and `p2` where values of the sample, but those are positions of the respective values which are to be summed up. At the point of writing this answer it wasn't quite clear what exactly the input of the function should be. I'll update once OP says whether or not this answers his question.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I didn't copy the code to every detail but the process you used and the steps the code takes helped me a lot in making my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a smaller generic function like so, which will change your sample by adding together two chosen values of the sample:

```
change_sample <- function(sample, i1, i2) {
    
    new_sample <- sample
    new_sample[i2] <- sample[i1] + sample[i2]
    
    return(new_sample[-i1])

}
```

If you then want to apply this multiple times, you could chain each application of this function together to achieve your goal.

Comment: I'm assuming [i1] and [i2] are the two values the user has decided to add up, I think i get the method, correct me if I'm wrong but you're taking the values i1 and i2, adding them and replacing i2 with the new value, then removing i1 from the sample?